# missing local hard driver after installing ubuntu over windows 10

Tags: hard-drive

I can not find my local hard drive . don't know if the installation went wrong or it's  just gone ... I'm absolutely beginner
some help would be great , as simple as u can plz ^*^ thanks in advance ^*^

[I think it appears in my computer just like windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1KLBB.png)

Comment: What error messages is it giving? Can you edit your question to show screenshots, explain what you are trying to do, what commands you are running, etc please?

Comment: i'm not using any commands . i've just installed it and logged in and the D partition is gone and the capacity is combined together :(

Comment: What are you seeing? What did you expect to see? Do you have screen shots or anything? We can't help unless we know what's going on.

Comment: I expect it to be just like windows . I open my computer and find the local drives !! when I plug in a usb I find it but I can not find my own drives at the very same place they are supposed to be in :(  I've edited the question with a screenshoot of the computer

Comment: You probably chose to install Ubuntu on the whole disk. "Driver D" was not a disk, but a partition. So it is gone. You can restore files from it if you stop using the system right now.

Comment: Yes. I'd say you probably installed Linux over Windows. Recovering files at all will be difficult if not impossible without advanced forensic tools.

Comment: could u please explain in details how can I recover my files ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

unfortunately , I chose to install Ubuntu on thee whole disk instead of choosing what partition to be installed on , which caused the format of the whole disk before installation .

Comment: data recovery could be used through the program called photorec through the following command :    sudo photorec